# python, how to skip lines in a range loop

Tags: python, loops, range

In python language, I want to skip lines of a range loop (or xrange) without breaking the loop, as illustrated below:

```
for i in range(10):
    ... some code happening
    ... some code happening

    if (some statement == True):
        skip the next lines of the loop, but do not break the loop until finished

    ... some code happening
    ... some code happening
```

Comment: Use `continue`.

Comment: I would not recommend `continue`, you can always write better code without it. Do `if not expression: <some code happening>`

Comment: @coldspeed better in which form?

Comment: `continue` is a synonym for a `goto` jumping to place just after the loop. For the explanation why `goto` is to be avoided I would refer to the famous ["Go To Statement Considered Harmful"](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf) by Edgar Dijkstra.

Comment: @sophros Yet, how could continue be avoided if every line of the code inside the loop is depented to the previous line?

Comment: @user3060854 - for this reason you were suggested `if` statements structure in the answers below. And this is not the only way to structure you code... but it is beyond the comment to elaborate on this (e.g. [use dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881114/how-to-use-dictionary-instead-of-if-statement-in-python) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `continue`

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        continue
    print(i)
```

output:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just nest that block in a condition:

```
for i in range(10):
    ... some code happening
    ... some code happening

    if not some_statement:

        ... some code happening
        ... some code happening
```